# Extraction of value using Regular Expression Extractor using JMeter

Tags: json, jmeter

I have following values

```
[
{
"id": ID1,
"XXX": "XXXX",
"XXX": "XXX XXX",
"xxx": {
  "XXXX": "XXXX",
  "XXXXX": "XXXX"
},
"XXXX": "XXXX@XXXX.com",
"XXXXX": "XXXX",
"XXXX": XXX,
"Section1": [
  {
    "id": ID_Section1,
    "xXXX": "XXXX",
    "teams": {
      "XXXX: XXX,
      "XXX": "XXX XXX XXX"
    },
    "Section2": {
      "id": ID_Section2,
      "XXXX": "XXX XX",
      "XXX": "XXX",
      "XXX": "XX-XX"
    },
    "XXX": XXX
  }
 {
"id": ID2,
"XXX": "XXXX",
"XXX": "XXX XXX",
"xxx": {
```

I need to get the value like ID1, ID2 etc. but while using the below regular expression, I am getting all the values of other ID as well like ID_Section1, ID_Section2 which I don't need.

Expression:

```
 "id":(.?),
```

Template : $1$

I also tried to extract the value using JSON path extractor with the below command but still it is fetching all the values.

```
 $..id
```

Any help is appreciated?

Comment: Use a json parser to parse json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply **don't use regular expressions to parse JSON**.

JMeter comes with [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which allows executing JsonPath language queries for getting data from JSON entities so you can get the "ID" you are interested in using simple query like: `$[0].id`

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSON Demo]

References:

- [JsonPath - Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks. Since I needed to get all the id values, I used your solution with bit of modification. Instead of using $[0].id, I used $[*].id which did the trick for me. Thanks for the help. I have accepted your answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What about this: `(?:"|')id(?:"|')\s*:\s*(?<id>ID\d+)`

It captures ID1, ID2 etc. in the named capturing group **id**.

You can try this solution online at: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thanks for the help but I was getting an error "org.apache.oro.text.MalformedCachePatternException: Invalid expression: (?:"|')id(?:"|')\s*:\s*(?<id>ID\d+)
Sequence (?<...) not recognized". Anyway, I have accepted the answer provided above. Thanks for the help anyway. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for the regular expression:

```
{\n"id":(.*?),
```

It will get ID1, ID2....and store them in different variables.

Comment: Thanks but with the above code, I was getting 0 matching counts. Anyway, I have accepted the answer provided above. Thanks for the help anyway. Cheers.

Comment: It is working for me, you can check here https://regex101.com/r/5wcotU/1